# Monitoring File I/O on file Server.

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to monitoring the file I/O on my file server. I want to gather some metrics on my current file system. I am running an old windows 2003 file server and I am planning on moving to a new file server running either windows server 2008 or 2012. I want to use these metrics and get a new file server that improve file I/O and access. Can some please advise me to what is the best way to monitor file access and get file I/O information so I can upgrade to a better file server.

Answer (score 0):

Download a tool such as Sysinternals ProcExplorer to view open file handles and concurrent disk access.

Of course you can pretty much do the same thing with the built-in perfmon and Task Explorer utilities.

Comment: Does this keep a history of all File I/O and track which users are using the file server the most?

Comment: History, yes, the users using it no, then again your original question didn't ask for that either.

Comment: I wanted any metrics in general to the file server, do you know of another services that give more that just that

Comment: @jenglee You need to specify what metrics you are looking to capture, your question implies you are only looking for size and rate of access.  If you want more than that you need to specify what they are.

Comment: Performance Monitor and Server Performance Analyzer are two tools you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Process Monitor (again, SysInternals) has some very good summary reports.  Out of the box though, Performance Monitor (perfmon) will give I/O figures (read, write or both), plus disk performance.  You might be more interested in the actual disk performance (random reads, random writes, sustained reads (streaming), etc).  I've used MS' SQLIO for this in the past.  Takes a few mins to get working, but it's good for benchmarking.  You can then run the same test on your new server, with the same config file, to see if things have improved.

If you are going to be running VSS Shadow Copies on your server, definitel use 2008R2 or 2012 (i.e.: x64).  Install plenty of RAM, and ensure your page file is at least RAM*1.5.  I'm only recommending this from experience.  We're running file servers of this spec. with 20+ TB of online data with no problem (24GB of RAM, though!).  These servers run on-access virus scanning and multiple VSS snapshots during the day.

Don't get too hung up about your NICs - a fault-tolerant 1Gbps NIC configuration will be ample.  Your bottleneck will still be disk.

Comment: If I'm storing 20+ TB of space or more I would be overly concerned about network as I would have offloaded all of the storage to a redundant storage array device and the load would now be on that 1Gbps connection, not the disk or the storage array.